# Dynamically filter ListView CBV in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django, listview, get, django-views

I've read the [official documentation on dynamically filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) ListView, but am still confused about how to actually use it.

I currently have a simple model, let's call it `Scholarship`:

```
class Scholarship(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date Submitted')
    EXPERIENCE_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'Any'),
        ('S', 'Student'),
        ('G', 'Graduate')
    )
    experience_level = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=EXPERIENCE_LEVEL_CHOICES, default='A')
```

I have a page where I'm showing all of these scholarships, using ListView:

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Scholarship


class ScholarshipDirectoryView(ListView):
    model = Scholarship
    template_name = 'scholarship-directory.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import ScholarshipDirectoryView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ScholarshipDirectoryView.as_view(), name='scholarship_directory'),
)
```

I'm trying to generate links on the home page of the site that will return filtered versions of this ListView. For example, if someone clicks on a "show scholarships for graduate students" link, only scholarships with `experience_level='G'` will be shown.

I have no problem returning this queryset via the shell -> `Scholarship.objects.filter(experience_level__exact='G')`

I'm just unsure about how to dynamically filter the ListView via a dropdown or URL. Not looking to use a plugin, but rather understand how dynamically querying/filtering works in Django.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you need to change your urls.py so that it'll pass the experience as a parameter. Something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<exp>[ASG])$', ScholarshipDirectoryView.as_view(), name='scholarship_directory'),
)
```

(the above will return 404 if /A or /S or /G is not passed)

Now, in  `kwargs` attribute of the CBV we will have a kwarg named `exp` which can be used by the `get_queryset` method to filter by experience level.

```
class ScholarshipDirectoryView(ListView):
    model = Scholarship
    template_name = 'scholarship-directory.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ScholarshipDirectoryView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(experience_level__exact=self.kwargs['exp'])
```

Comment: You can also access kwargs in `get_queryset` with `self.kwargs`.

Comment: Ooops yes you are right, I'd forgot about self.kwargs !! I changed my answer to reflect that (and be more DRY). thanks !

Comment: @Serafeim any idea how to default to queryset if kwarg is not in the url? I would like to use same url conf for filtered and unfiltered

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible having an optional parameter in the url - experience has to be provide to use that url conf line. So you need to eithet add an other url line with out the parameter (so you'll have two lines for the same view) or call back to using good old GET parameters to passing experience (?exp=A).

Comment: Ok. I understand. So what If I wan't to return the original QS when the Filtered list is empty? @Serafeim

Comment: @villancikos Please ask a new question. The comments area isn't for new questions.

Comment: I suggest adding a check on self.kwargs to see if the filter keyword has been supplied, and just returning the original qs if not.  i.e. after `qs = super(...` add `if 'exp' in self.kwargs: ... and return filtered qs as above, else just return qs.  This makes it work with or without the filter.  When I tried the answer, it worked for filtering but my original unfiltered view was broken.

Comment: Have you used the same url config? Using the provided urls the exp parameter will be always there (or else that specific url won't match) thus the check isn't really needed in this exact case.