# django filtering by user id in Class based ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-1.8, django-generic-views

I have a class based ListView of which I would like to filter the objects by the logged in user_id since Item model has a foreign key to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

```
class ItemListView(LoginRequiredMixin, StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
  model = Item
  template_name = "items/list_items.html"
```

In function based views I can do this using request.user but not in generic Class based views. Any ideas of how to best do this?

Here is the Item model

```
class Item(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically filter ListView CBV in Django 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662374/dynamically-filter-listview-cbv-in-django-1-7)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can override get_queryset function in ListView and filter on self.request.user

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Item.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the redundant code since you have already defined the model field in your class-based view:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
```