# Dynamic Filtering in Django with default Queryset

Tags: python, django, listview

I've read the excellent explanation in this question 
[Dynamically filter ListView CBV in Django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662374/dynamically-filter-listview-cbv-in-django-1-7).

But I wan't to get extra help on the queryset.

```
# urls.py
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^(?P<exp>[ASG])$', \
          ScholarshipDirectoryView.as_view(),\
          name='scholarship_directory'),)

# views.py
class ScholarshipDirectoryView(ListView):
    queryset= Scholarship.objects.all()
    model = Scholarship
    template_name = 'scholarship-directory.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ScholarshipDirectoryView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(experience_level__exact=self.kwargs['exp'])
```

What is the DRY way to fallback to the standard queryset in case the "exp" parameter is missing in the url?

I want to take on this approach because I don't think doing an extra view or extra urlpattern for the complete Queryset and the Custom/Filtered Queryset makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in an `if`.

```
    qs = super(ScholarshipDirectoryView, self).get_queryset()
    exp =  self.kwargs['exp']
    if exp:
        qs = qs.filter(experience_level__exact=exp)
    # return the new or the old queryset.
    return qs
```

Comment: What is being repeated?

Comment: You're right. Nothing is being repeated. Although I'm not getting it to work. It returns the full qs.

Comment: I forgot to add that if the filter does not return any objects then it should fallback to the original qs.